# Chrome Developer Tools: What do the black vertical bars in the frame capture represent?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I am a bit confused by what information frame section of the Performance tab is telling me:

The black vertical bars seem to indicate that there are dozens of frames happening during the period that is spanned by the green time interval of 1386.5ms however, the green vertical bar seems to represent exactly 1 frame.

Clearly, frames do not happen within frames.

So, my question is what do the vertical black bars represent and what does the green bar representing the 1386.5ms time interval represent? Right now it seems that the information one conveys contradicts the other.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated! ❤

[image: Snapshot of Performance Tab in Chrome Developer Tools]

[image: Left: several arrows pointing to black vertical lines that seem to represent frames. Right: an arrow pointing to the green bar representing a time interval of exactly one frame.]

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, I updated my question to reflect that my confusion stems from not understanding what information the vertical black bars and the combination of the green time interval + the tooltip that says ~1fps are trying to convey.

Comment: The tooltip shows an "instant fps", essentially 1000 / frameLengthInMilliseconds. It's just a minor insignificant convenience for those who don't want to remember the exact frame duration for various common frame rates like 16.6ms for 60fps which is the minimum desired frame rate.

Comment: I don't see such dark black lines here so I guess it's a bug or a misleadingly emphasized grid for the time axis.

Comment: @wOxxOm If you want to write that as an answer I will mark it as correct. Appreciate your clarifications 

Comment: I'd like to have a look at this myself first. Can you share a jsfiddle or URL? Or maybe just export/save the results (there's a button in the toolbar) and upload it somewhere?